# Forgot password reset not displaying correct email address and not updating password if any error made by user during for submission

Tags: php, forms, email, mysqli

I am currently working on PHP forgot password reset, which partially doing the job but seeking some assistance to improve it further.

1st issue: It is not displaying the correct email address on the
    submission form. It updates the password correctly but doesn't
    display correct email address.

2nd issue: Also if the user makes an error while submitting the form on reloading the page doesn't update the password hence the user has to go back to his email to click back on the link.

```
  <?php
        include('../config/connection.php'); 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          $password   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['password']);
          $Rpassword  = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['Rpassword']);
          $acode=$_POST['encrypt'];
          $passmd = md5(SHA1($password));
        if (empty($password) OR empty($Rpassword)) {
           $error = 'One or either field is missing';
        } if ($password != $Rpassword) {
           $error = 'Passwords don\'t match';
        } if(strlen($password)<6 OR strlen($Rpassword)>20) {
            $error = 'Password must be between 6 to 20 characters';
        }
        else {
            $query = mysqli_query($dbc,"select * from users where passreset='$acode'") or die(mysqli_error($dbc)); 

        if (mysqli_num_rows ($query)==1) 
        {
          $query3 = mysqli_query($dbc,"UPDATE users SET password='$passmd',passreset=0 WHERE passreset='$acode'")
        or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
          $sent = 'Password has been Changed successfully, Please <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> for loging in.';
        }
        else
            {
              $error = 'Please click back on the Forgot password link to reset your password ';
            }
        }
    }
?>

        <body>
              <?php if(!isset($_POST['submit']) OR $error != '' OR isset($error)) { ?>

          <?php if(isset($error) AND $error !='')
          {
              echo '<p style="color:#c43235">'.$error.'</p>'; 

              }
                       ?>

            <form action="reset.php" method="post" role="form"> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"  value="
                    <?php 
                     $acode=$_POST['encrypt'];
                     $query5 = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM users where passreset='$acode'") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));  
                     $list = mysqli_fetch_array($query5); /* Error-----*/
                     $val = $list['email'];
                    echo $val;?>" >
               </div>  


               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
               </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Re-enter Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="Rpassword" placeholder="Password" >
               </div>


               <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="encrypt" value="<?php echo $_GET['encrypt'];?>" >


                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" />Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Why did you hash your password twice `$passmd = md5(SHA1($password));`?

Comment: What do you suggest, I thought its better to store it hashed...

Comment: For one thing, there is nothing assigned for the `email` name attribute (no $_POST). The only assignment here is `$val = $list['email'];`

Comment: Seems (but unclear) that you are using the user email as a condition to reset the password. Isn't it? If I am wrong, then why are you using that value in email input in your form. Let me know what how do you get that $acode

Comment: Than do it one time SHA1 is preferred because MD5 is not safe anymore.

Comment: I honestly don't know why you're doing `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"  value="
                        <?php 
                        $acode=$_POST['encrypt'];
                        $query5 = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM users where passreset='$acode'") or die(mysqli_error($dbc));  
                        $list = mysqli_fetch_array($query5); /* Error-----*/
                        $val = $list['email'];
                        echo $val;?>" >` - you could use a hidden attribute for it in the fetched results.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()`. Use `var_dump();` also and view your HTML source.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I wd like the user to be able to see the email address for which he is changing the password, I cd surely hide it...

Comment: @rehmat, didn't mean to confuse email is not the condition to update password but $acode which is a random hased number that will come up on reset link as per below.
$encrypt = md5(rand(200,200000),$num_id); $acode=$_POST['encrypt'];
reset link: http://1200.0.0.0/abc.com/cgi-bin/admin/reset.php?encrypt='.$encrypt.'

Comment: If you get it from the link, then you should use $_GET['encrypt'] instead $_POST['encrypt']

Comment: Like I said, check for errors and use `var_dump()` and view your HTML source to see what's being passed or not. Those are valuable developer's/debugging tools. You'll know what to go after.

Comment: I'm trying to test this for you, and using your posted code, is generating an unexpected end of file error. Your posted code is missing a `}`.

Comment: In testing so far, and as I already said about viewing your HTML source, there are errors in there and your email input is broken `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"  value="` and `email@example.com" >` is broken on another line with an added space, along with unused divs. You have enough to go on now. Remember, HTML source can be just as good a "tool" as any. You should be querying, assigning a variable to it, then using that as the value. Get rid of the extra spaces and replace that by `name="email"  value="<?php `.

Comment: Also, get rid of the extra space in `echo $val;?>" >` to `echo $val;?>">`

Comment: Thanks @rehmat...issue 1 resolved now :-). Can you also plz help with 2nd issue.